# LWC Superbadge Step 3 - Setup / Clarification

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, superbadges

Everything leading up to this challenge has been done in VSCode and SFDX. Should I be editing the code for the challenges in the Developer Console or is there a way to pull the code into VSCode? I have authorized the Project Default org, is that the correct ORG to be working in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the times, you will be creating new things. But, yeah some things (like BoatDataService apex class) are already created for you. You can make changes to the apex class in the developer console, but for LWC, you have to retrieve them to the VS code by using the retrieve command.

For example:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle:boatMap
```